# React Native programming undo/redo

Tags: ios, react-native, undo

I'm wondering what the basic principle of programming undo and redo is? Specifically in React Native. I'm a beginner programmer and I can't figure out how undo would be programmed since it just reverses anything at all.

Use solitaire card game for example, you can place a card onto an end of one of the card rows, simply turn a card over in the source pile or place a card from the card rows up onto the ace piles. These are all straightforward to program but how would you implement a simple 'undo' button that reverses any of these moves? And potentially to an unlimited extent.

Comment: You could keep the state in an array, and add a new element to the array as you move forward, and when you undo, you could simple remove the last element of the array, or move backwards by one.

Comment: I guess so but you'd have to have several different states for all the different kinds of movements possible. I just wonder how the basic concept is programmed. Like in Photoshop for example, there are literally a billion different things you can do, and then just click undo to reverse any single one. You'd have to record the state of every possible action.

Comment: @Hasen, yep that's exactly what they do. Every action in the whole app has  a function that knows how to 'do' the action and how to 'undo' the action. These are stored in a list as the user selections options and performs changes

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. I think I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

A basic example of how to maintain state

http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ImplementingUndoHistory.html

```
let state = {
  past:[],
  present: 0,
  future: [],
};

const canUndo = state.past.length > 0;
const canRedo = state.future.length > 0;

const updateState = function(value) {
  state.past = state.present;
  state.present = value;
};

const undo = function() {
  state.future.push(state.present);
  state.present = state.past.pop();
};

const redo = function() {
  state.past.push(state.present);
  state.present = state.present.pop();
};
```

A plugin for redux that gives you redo/undo

https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-undo